# Problem with titleformat: Don't want Chapter Style to be Applicable on Table of Contents & Bibliography

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titletoc

Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,
   left=23mm,  %% or inner=23mm
   right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
   top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip,
   headsep=7mm,
   footskip=7mm
}


%% Command to hold chapter illustration image
\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

%% Define how the chapter title is printed
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
%% Background image at top of page
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
%% Draw a semi-transparent rectangle across the top
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[LightSalmon1,opacity=.7]
  (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-3cm] current page.north east);
  %% Check if on an odd or even page
  \checkoddpage\strictpagecheck
  %% On odd pages, "logo" image at lower right
  %% corner; Chapter number printed near spine
  %% edge (near the left); chapter title printed
  %% near outer edge (near the right).
  \ifoddpage{
    \ThisLRCornerWallPaper{.35}{fern_mo_01}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries, 
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=east, 
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at (current page.north east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  %% On even pages, "logo" image at lower left
  %% corner; Chapter number printed near outer
  %% edge (near the right); chapter title printed
  %% near spine edge (near the left).
  \else {
    \ThisLLCornerWallPaper{.35}{fern_mo_01}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north east)
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries,
      inner sep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at ( current page.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{six-computers-chips-circuits}
\newpage
\chapter{Hello World!}


\renewcommand\chapterillustration{cherry-tomatos}
\newpage
\chapter{Whassup, Doc?}

\end{document}
```

Problem:

The Fancy Settings which I applied to "Chapters" comes over to Everything in the Document.
=> Table of Contents & Bibliography(not included in the sample code above) are now displayed as 'Chapters'.

Also, I have to disable:

```
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
```

as enabling these sections leads to compilation error (when the Chapter Settings applies to them).

Please help me find some way to avoid this problem.

Comment: When I try to compile your MWE in pdflatex, I get the following error message: file `! LaTeX Error: File \`six-computers-chips-circuits' not found.` Please consider modifying the MWE to avoid requiring this type of (unnecessary?) dependency.

Comment: "six-computers-chips-circuits", "cherry-tomatos", "fern_mo_01" are images, you can rename any images in your system to these names, or you can download from this example code: http://liantze.googlepages.com/samplebookdesign-fancychapter-titles.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the table of contents comes before the numbered chapters, you could move your `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands after `\tableofcontents`, so this won't be affected.

You could also define commands, which act like a switch: one calls `\titleformat` and `\titlesection` the fancy way, and the other calls it with default settings, which can be found in the `titlesec` documentation appendix. So you can switch if on and off as you like.

Here's a small example for switching styles, which can be a start for you - just changing colors:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\fancychapterstyle}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{blue}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge\color{blue}}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}
\newcommand*{\standardchapterstyle}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\fancychapterstyle
\chapter{One}
\standardchapterstyle
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have gone through the titlesec documentation, but couln't find anything which can give me control to switch between formats. Can you please point out any specific section/example? Also, I think that these commands must be placed in preamble section only. How can I call them from middle of the document?

Comment: @SandeepSingh Define your own macro in your preamble. Within this macro, call `\titleformat` with any option you like. You can use your new macro within the document.

Comment: @SandeepSingh `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` can be used anywhere in the document, not just in the preamble.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Please excuse my ignorance on this. I got confused after reading some post. One point: I have placed /tableofcontents,  // New Chapter Settings {Using \titleformat, Chapters ..... . Before BIBLIOGRAPHY, I want to RESTORE Default Settings Again, please give some hint on how to do this.

Comment: @SandeepSingh No problem. `\standardchapterstyle` as defined by Stefan in his answer allows you to restore the default settings. Copy his definition of the command in the preamble and use `\standardchapterstyle` before the bibliography (as he did in his example).