# title chapter in middle of page latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, titlesec

I try to put title of my chapter in middle of page, so google it and i finish with this,

```
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{200pt}{40pt}
```

okay that make all chapter title in middle, but no,  I want to make all chapter title in middle except introduction and conclusion and title of table of contents, list of figures

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More search to find the solution, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68721/53897) , and also with explanation thanks to **@Stefan Kottwitz**  it was clear and simple.

just change in **fancychapterstyle** `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}` to  `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}` to make it center vertically  and follow the explanation of **@Stefan Kottwitz**

Comment: thanks to you **Zero-dev** and to **Stefan Kottwitz** that's solve my subject