# Personalize title 2

Tags: chapters, titlesec, tcolorbox

Seeing my previous question (solved), I have another doubt. 
Now that I have personalize also the contents, the TOC style is in conflict with the chapters style.
There is another thread about this 
[question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/problem-with-titleformat-dont-want-chapter-style-to-be-applicable-on-table-of).

Now, I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bm,graphicx,empheq}
\usepackage{units,cancel,mathtools,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{varwidth,verbatim,setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize,rotating,framed,titletoc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,contour}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,multirow,marginnote}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=black,bookmarksdepth=3, urlcolor=black}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=0,color=red]{bookmark}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\newcommand*{\fancychapterstyle}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=14.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{red}\Huge\sf\bfseries \thechapter};%
\draw[fill=red,draw=red] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=14.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sf\bfseries\thechapter};%
\end{tikzpicture}}
  {20pt}{\tcbset{enhanced,width=\textwidth, interior style=white,before skip=1mm,after skip=1mm,
colbacktitle=white,boxrule=0mm,colframe=black,
left=0mm,right=0mm,boxsep=0mm,sharp corners}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
        \node[text width=15cm,text=transparent!20]
        {\fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont\textbf{\textsf{\chaptertitlename}}\\};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=15cm-2mm,text opacity=0,shade,path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,top color=violet,bottom color=red]
        {\fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont{\selectfont\textbf{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}}\\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents %just inserted here to show that have a different style from the other chapters.
\fancychapterstyle
\chapter{one}

\chapter{very long long title number two}

\end{document}
```

But instead of \chaptertitlename I wanted the very title of the chapter (it print the word "chapter").
I tried to write nothing but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a remark: I don't think you can use both `titletoc` and `tocloft`. Also, needless to load `amsmath` if you load `empheq`.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, now I check if this is the problem =)

Comment: Nothing, the fact is that in the other question if nothing is written (instead of \chaptertitlename) it print what I want

Comment: What you try to achieve is not quite clear to me. If your chapter has a title, say ‘L'inferno’, you want to obtain `L'inferno` instead of `Chapter 3`?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: I don't have time at the moment, but I'll try to see that a little later, if no one  has brought a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimizing the code to what is necessary and removing strange font selections (in particular I removed `\scshape` that's not available for most sans serif fonts).

Since you call `titlesec` with the `explicit` option, the chapter title is available as `#1`, not as `\chaptertitlename`. In your case you have to use `##1` as you're placing the code in a macro definition (which I'm unsure the usefulness of).

```
\documentclass[twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  anchorcolor=black,
  citecolor=black,
  bookmarksdepth=3,
  urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=0,color=red]{bookmark}

\newcommand*{\fancychapterstyle}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
     \pgftext[right,x=14.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{red}\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter};%
     \draw[fill=red,draw=red] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
     \clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
     \pgftext[right,x=14.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter};%
     \end{tikzpicture}}
     {20pt}
     {\tcbset{
        enhanced,width=\textwidth, interior style=white,before skip=1mm,after skip=1mm,
        colbacktitle=white,boxrule=0mm,colframe=black,
        left=0mm,right=0mm,boxsep=0mm,sharp corners
     }%
     \begin{tcolorbox}
     \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
       \node[
         text width=15cm,
         text=transparent!20
       ]{\fontsize{50}{70}\sffamily\bfseries\ ##1\\};
     \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[
         text width=15cm-2mm,
         text opacity=0,
         shade,
         path fading=tikz,
         fit fading=false,
         top color=violet,
         bottom color=red
      ]{\fontsize{50}{70}\sffamily\bfseries ##1\\};
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{tcolorbox}}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}

\begin{document}
\fancychapterstyle

\tableofcontents %just inserted here to show that have a different style from the other chapters.
\chapter{one}

\chapter{very long long title number two}

\end{document}
```

The style in the TOC page is the same as for other chapters, because I moved the `\fancychapterstyle` declaration before it.

[image]